# Continuous duty tolerance for automotive resistors

Tags: resistors, switches

What is the designation for resistors to be used in 12 v automotive applications?  The resistor would pass 5-10 V continuous while the vehicle is switched on. The goal is to lower the standardized switching temperature range for automotive coolant controls. I think this is a watt question.

Comment: I think this is a What??? question. There is either far too much context -  ie just use a suitably rated resistor for the application, or far too little - link to auto coolant controls, and the particular one you're using, what does 'standardised' mean, how much lower,  etc?

Comment: What current is the resistor expected to carry, and what voltage drop is required?  Or what is the resistance?

Comment: Sorry Pat, there is no answer to be given.  You need to understand and be able to describe the electrical characteristics of the circuit in question to select appropriate resistors.   It's not like mechanical stuff, where you just keep picking nuts out of your goody bag until you find one that fits the bolt.